# MySQL search one letter word

Tags: mysql, sql, boolean

I'm using BOOLEAN MODE in MySQL and want it to return results with one-letter words.

The below SQL works for C# and C++, but if the user searches C it will return C++ and C# as well.  Does anyone know how I can make it only return results containing C?

```
select 
    jobs.id, 
    MATCH(jobs.job_title,jobs.job_description) AGAINST ('c' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance
from jobs 
    where jobs.status='on' and MATCH(jobs.job_title,jobs.job_description) AGAINST ('c' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    group by jobs.id 
    order by relevance
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL, the default minimum word length is 4 characters.   You can modify this in the server system variables (be careful doing this).  You would need to set the ft_min_word_len to a smaller number (e.g. 1).  The documentation is here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html and here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to mention that this change has already been made to the server, which makes me think it's due to the sql query I'm running.

Comment: If you are using InnoDB, the default is 3, and it is set by a different VARIABLE.